# custom class = custom +alloc , custom +init

Tags: objective-c

I'm new with objective c for the iphone.

I'm writing a custom class, then, should I write my own +alloc, +init methods?
I believe that: the +alloc will just call [thing alloc]; and the +init will perform something like: [thing setValue:X];

is there a "default" +alloc and +init methods?
if yes, what should I wait for the default +alloc and +init?, let's say i have a NSMutableDictionary*
i.e.

```
@interface class1 : NSObject {

    NSString *test; 
    NSMutableDictionary *map;
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You generally don't need to write your own +alloc method.

For your example, you might have an -init that looks like:

```
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        map = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionary] retain];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Note that you first call the superclass `-init`, and check that it worked, before initializing your own variables.

Answer (score 2):

You should **NEVER** override `alloc`.

As for `init`, which is an **instance method**, by the way, **yes** that would be the place where you'd probably want to set up your variables.

Comment: I read that a few times now. However, I would like to know, is that a property (haha see what I did? *g*) of the language, or of the framework?

In other words, would @synthesize still work if I don't derive my class from NSObject, and don't tell the compiler to use Foundation?